# Azure Automation Runbooks using Get-Credential without parameters

Tags: azure

There are several Runbooks examples in the Azure Runbook Gallery, such as:

- *Deploy a Windows Azure Web Site Pointing to a SQL Database and Storage Account*

that use the following syntax with `Get-Credential`:

```
$credential = Get-Credential
```

which implies that the command should prompt for the credentials -- but this fails in a Runbook with the following message:

> Get-Credential : Cannot process command because of one or more missing mandatory parameters: Credential.

The credentials that are desired here are for this purpose:

```
# Get credentials from user to setup administrator access to new SQL Azure Server
```

which then should get used in downstream cmdlet calls in the Runbook such as

```
$databaseServer = New-AzureSqlDatabaseServer -AdministratorLogin $credential.UserName `
    -AdministratorLoginPassword $credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password -Location $Location
```

But because `Get-Credential` fails the downstream calls fail.

What I am doing wrong?

Why does a Runbook in the Gallery have statements that seem to be incompatible (prompt for Credentials) with allowable Runbook behaviors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So with Azure Automation, you would create a credential asset (for example, named AzureAdmin) and then you would reference that in the runbook, to get those credentials:

```
$cred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name AzureAdmin
```

As for the reference script, I suppose, it was just added to the runbook gallery without any verification, so in reality its not Azure Automation friendly

Comment: Your suggestion allows for the Runbook to function correctly -- thanks for that.  However I would not expect to use the Automation account credentials for the `-Administrator` login for the SQL Server instance.  I would expect this ordinarily to be targeted to a 'human' account rather than a 'service/automation' account.  I want to use my the account I have my Azure subscription set up under -- but I don't think that `Get-AutomationPSCredential` will work for that account.  Trying it now.

Comment: why not? you can create a credential asset for any account. its just a way to store credentials..., you would access username and password as `$cred.Username` and `$cred.Password`